# How can you add style from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How this style can be added in javascript?

```css
.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}
```

Comment: please make sure you provide more infos. How can we help you if we do not know what you want to achieve? Where do you want to add that class? Provide some javascript sample.

Comment: Why do you need JS? Just add a `table` class to the table element.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve by doing it with jJS? Why not just style it with css? your question needs to be more clear, and more depth needs to be added for context..

Answer (score 0):

Put all that in a `css` file, then inject it like so (edit the `path-to/your-css-file.css` bit):

```
  let link = document.createElement('link');
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = 'path-to/your-css-file.css';
  document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classList first, create a class includes this styles. Then, use this on JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("example").classList.add("className");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const style = document.createElement('style');

style.textContent=`
.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td {
padding: 8px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
vertical-align: top;
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
}`;
 
 document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Hope the above code helps...